# How to rotate viewport?

Tags: camera

I've tried changing the pivot port and everything like that and using the help page but I can't find a way to do what I'm trying to do. is there a way to rotate the entire viewport by a strict 90 degrees? I want to go from the left to the right.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are asking? The question refers to rotating the **viewport**, but you mention moving the pivot point and the picture shows the hand model rotated ~90 degrees. If you want to rotate the hand, just hold down the ctrl key while rotating and it will snap to 5 degree increments. Alternatively, just select the hand in object mode, press N to bring up the side menu, and type 90 into whatever rotation axis you want.

Comment: Yeep. You are very right. Just had a mental malfunction. Thanks